# Adapter not getting boolean values to set spinner selection

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using firebase recycler options to retrieve data needed from firebase database, which in this case 3 boolean value. In the adapter, i found out that all boolean value retrieved is false. However, when i start the activity and select the spinner, the spinner correctly set up the boolean value in firebase database. Moreover, the selection on the spinner not set correctly according to the data, as it retrieve all false in the database.

I attached my helper class, adapter onbindviewholder and onitemselected.

BookingModal.class

```
public class BookingModal {

    private String DATE;
    private String TIME;
    private String UID;
    private boolean approved;
    private boolean pending;
    private boolean rejected;

    public BookingModal(String DATE, String TIME, String UID, boolean approved, boolean pending, boolean rejected) {
        this.DATE = DATE;
        this.TIME = TIME;
        this.UID = UID;
        this.approved = approved;
        this.pending = pending;
        this.rejected = rejected;
    }
    public BookingModal(){}

    public String getDATE() {
        return DATE;
    }

    public void setDATE(String DATE) {
        this.DATE = DATE;
    }

    public String getTIME() {
        return TIME;
    }

    public void setTIME(String TIME) {
        this.TIME = TIME;
    }

    public String getUID() {
        return UID;
    }

    public void setUID(String UID) {
        this.UID = UID;
    }


    public boolean Approved() {
        return approved;
    }

    public void setApproved(boolean approved) {
        this.approved = approved;
    }

    public boolean Pending() {
        return pending;
    }

    public void setPending(boolean pending) {
        this.pending = pending;
    }

    public boolean Rejected() {
        return rejected;
    }

    public void setRejected(boolean rejected) {
        this.rejected = rejected;
    }
}
```

Adapter onbindviewholder class.

```
  @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BookingVH holder, int position, @NonNull BookingModal model) {

        holder.date.setText(model.getDATE());

        UserModal userModalDetail = findbyProperty(userModalList, model.getUID());
        if (userModalDetail != null) {
            holder.name.setText(userModalDetail.getName());
            holder.matric.setText(userModalDetail.getMatricnumber());
            onStatusSelected.onSelected(holder.status, userModalDetail.getUID(), model);
        }

        Log.d("booleanvalue", model.Pending() + " - "+model.Approved()+" - "+model.Rejected());



    }
```

onitemselected for spinner

```
 @Override
    public void onSelected(Spinner v, String uid, BookingModal modal) {
        Log.d("modalboolean", String.valueOf(modal.Approved()));
        v.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                checker.clear();
                if (i == 0){
                    mDatabase.child("Bookings").child("Kompleks Sukan A").child("Pending").child(uid).child("isPending").setValue(true);
                    mDatabase.child("Bookings").child("Kompleks Sukan A").child("Pending").child(uid).child("isApproved").setValue(false);
                    mDatabase.child("Bookings").child("Kompleks Sukan A").child("Pending").child(uid).child("isRejected").setValue(false);

                } else if (i == 1){
                    mDatabase.child("Bookings").child("Kompleks Sukan A").child("Pending").child(uid).child("isApproved").setValue(true);
                    mDatabase.child("Bookings").child("Kompleks Sukan A").child("Pending").child(uid).child("isPending").setValue(false);
                    mDatabase.child("Bookings").child("Kompleks Sukan A").child("Pending").child(uid).child("isRejected").setValue(false);


                } else if (i == 2){
                    mDatabase.child("Bookings").child("Kompleks Sukan A").child("Pending").child(uid).child("isRejected").setValue(true);
                    mDatabase.child("Bookings").child("Kompleks Sukan A").child("Pending").child(uid).child("isApproved").setValue(false);
                    mDatabase.child("Bookings").child("Kompleks Sukan A").child("Pending").child(uid).child("isPending").setValue(false);

                }
                v.setSelection(i, true);

                Log.d("CheckerMap", checker.toString());
//                mDatabase.child("Bookings").child("Kompleks Sukan A").child("Pending").child(uid).updateChildren(checker);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Really appreciate for any help. Thank you in advance !

**EDITED**

Here is my json db structure

```
{
  "Admin": {
    "e7oK2kaWLDW5SdSnBS1KEKXazNH3": {
      "admin": true,
      "departmentnumber": "",
      "email": "admin@mail.com",
      "matricnumber": "",
      "name": "admin1",
      "password": "admin123",
      "phonenumber": ""
    }
  },
  "Bookings": {
    "Kompleks Sukan A": {
      "Pending": {
        "AQ7W0xjc0kYZTg7mz5LH8m7wAXF3": {
          "DATE": "19/01/2023",
          "TIME": "1-2PM",
          "UID": "AQ7W0xjc0kYZTg7mz5LH8m7wAXF3",
          "isApproved": true,
          "isPending": false,
          "isRejected": false
        },
        "a59Pmpt9kvNTO6yFjXspGRqmlGh1": {
          "date": "26/01/2023",
          "isApproved": false,
          "isPending": false,
          "isRejected": true,
          "time": "1-2PM",
          "uid": "a59Pmpt9kvNTO6yFjXspGRqmlGh1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Kompleks Sukan A": {
    "1-2PM": false,
    "10-11AM": false,
    "11-12PM": false,
    "12-1PM": false,
    "2-3PM": false,
    "3-4PM": false,
    "4-5PM": false,
    "5-6PM": false,
    "6-7PM": false,
    "9-10AM": false
  },
  "Users": {
    "AQ7W0xjc0kYZTg7mz5LH8m7wAXF3": {
      "admin": false,
      "departmentnumber": "",
      "email": "user1@mail.com",
      "matricnumber": "",
      "name": "test",
      "password": "user123",
      "phonenumber": "",
      "uid": "AQ7W0xjc0kYZTg7mz5LH8m7wAXF3"
    },
    "a59Pmpt9kvNTO6yFjXspGRqmlGh1": {
      "admin": false,
      "departmentnumber": "",
      "email": "ceyn@mail.com",
      "matricnumber": "53104119052",
      "name": "ceyn",
      "password": "ceyn123",
      "phonenumber": "01112872692",
      "uid": "a59Pmpt9kvNTO6yFjXspGRqmlGh1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a single string as status checking. Changing it easier to use with spinner.

Answer (score 0):

In your **POJO** classes, you have declared

```
private boolean approved;
private boolean pending;
private boolean rejected;
```

while generating build, android change variable names of `boolean` types.

To prevent this changing, you can keep your model classes in `Proguard Rules` as follow:

```
-keep class com.example.myapplication.models.**
```

keep all of your classes under `models` package. Now it will not change the names of variables.

Comment: it only then added date,time and uid. all the boolean values not set up when i insert the modal from user.

Comment: Then update your model class names to this `
          "isApproved",
          "isPending",
          "isRejected"`